# XCode's svn "abort trap: 6" message

Tags: svn, xcode4.4, xcode4.5

I've discovered problem with svn tool after updating XCode to version 4.4. I receive "Abort trap: 6" message every time I try to execute any command like list, checkout, etc.

For example:

```
berec-Mac:~ berec$ /Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/svn list https://source.com/mysource
Abort trap: 6
```

Thank you in advance for advise.

Comment: This problem appears only for my svn-source accessible via https (everything is ok with http svn-sources). One more thing -  I don't have such problems with old version of XCode (4.3.3).

Comment: I've found a solution here: http://post.niob.be/fix-mac-os-x-svn-ssl-bug-bad-decompression. The core of problem is the Neon svn module.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is [here](http://niob.be/development/2011/07/30/fix-os-x-svn-ssl-bug/). 
The core of my problem was the Neon svn module. To resolve XCode's svn client I just replaced Xcode's svn binary by svn binary containing Serf module.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `xcrun` ([reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcrun.1.html)):

```
$ xcrun svn list https://source.com/mysource
```

You might need to ensure that your `xcode-select` ([reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcode-select.1.html)) is configured correctly first though:

```
$ xcode-select -print-path
```

Which should come back with:

```
/Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer
```

If not, use:

```
$ xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode45-DP3.app/Contents/Developer
```

Comment: The same result (abort trap:6) with xcrun. "xcode-select -print-path" shows correct path.

Comment: @berec Can you bump up the verbosity (using `--verbose`) to see if `svn` gives some reason for the abort?

Comment: Unfortunatelly, --verbose shows nothing. Actually, I have noticed this problem appears only for my svn-source accessible via https (everything is ok with http svn-sources).

Answer (score 0):

Installing svn from [homebrew](https://brew.sh/):

```
brew install svn
```

Than using /usr/local/bin/svn.

Comment: Be careful with this...on my machine, Homebrew just installed a different version of SVN in a different location than I had used to check out my projects and I couldn't work with it. It left the other version of SVN intact and didn't actually solve anything.

Answer (score 0):

According to my assumptions there may be 2 reasons.

1) May be the network which you are using it's have lots of proxy settings which is making problem.

2) Download Xcode command run tools from Xcode --> preference.