# Assembla SVN checkout Error

Tags: svn, assembla

I am getting following error while I am doing `svn checkout`:

> Authentication realm: https://subversion.assembla.com:443 (null)
>   Password for '...':
>   Abort trap: 6

Any help?

Comment: Looks like this is question to Assembla support.

Comment: Ran into the same problem with Lion's command-line svn client. [Seems like it is broken for HTTPS.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757491/xcodes-svn-abort-trap-6-message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a svn client core dump.

What are you using to checkout your svn repository and what operating system are you on?  Can you authenticate in a web browser to your svn repository?  What happens when you try it from another computer or client?

You might need to reinstall your client or libsvn completely.

Comment: I am able to see/authenticate it in web browser but not able to checkout in terminal using svn command